# Vue: Proxy requests to a separate backend server with vue-cli

Tags: node.js, express, vue.js, vue-cli

I am using vue-cli webpack template to generate my projects, and I'd like to proxy requests to a separate, backend server. But I got the error message as follow.

Could anyone tell me what's the matter with my coding?

Thank you very much!

Error message

```
[HPM] Error occurred while trying to proxy request from localhost:8080 to http://localhost:3000 (ECONNREFUSED) (https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors)
```

config -> index.js

```
proxyTable: {
'/api':{
    target: 'http://localhost:3000',
    changeOrigin: true,
    pathRewrite: {
    '^/api': ''
    }
 }
```

src -> main.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import routerConfig from './router.config.js' 
import Axios from 'axios'


Vue.config.productionTip = false;
Vue.prototype.$axios = Axios;
Vue.prototype.HOST = '/api';

Vue.use(VueRouter);

const router = new VueRouter(routerConfig) 

new Vue({
 el: '#app',
 router,  
 components: { App }, 
 template: '<App/>',
})
```

src -> App.vue

```
export default{

created(){
  var url = this.HOST
  this.$axios.get(url,{

  }).then((res)=>{

   console.log(res.data)

  },(res)=>{

  alert(res.status)
  })
 }
}
```

server

```
const express = require('express');
const mysql = require('mysql');

const db = mysql.createPool({
  localhost:'localhost',
  user:'root',
  password:'123456',
  database:'blog'
})

const server = express();

server.use('/api',(req,res)=>{

db.query(`SELECT * FROM articles_table`,(err,data)=>{
   if(err){
     console.error(err);
     res.status(500).send('database error').end();
   }else{
     res.send(data)
   }
 })

})
server.listen(3000)
```

Comment: May seem too obvious, but... was your express server running when you got that error?

Comment: Sorry, Could you tell me how can I run the express server when I got the error? Fron-end and back-end have different port@acdcjunior

Comment: Say the content of that file you posted (with `const express = require('express'); ... server.listen(3000)`) is in `server.js`. You have to run it like `node server.js` (provided you ran `npm install` to dowload the `express` and `mysql` dependencies before)

Comment: Are you mean I need to run 'node server.js' at first?  But if I run 'node server.js', then I cannot run the 'npm run dev'...How can I do to solve that?@acdcjunior

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do as follows:

```
npm install --save-dev concurrently
```

Add to `scripts` at package.json:

```
"server": "node server.js",
"go": "concurrently --kill-others \"npm run dev\" \"npm run server\""
```

And use, from now on:

```
npm run go
```

Naturally, you can rename `go` to whatever you want.

Comment: Can you give it another try? I have changed the package.

Comment: Okay, I will create a project using cli here, I will test and let you know, ok? meanwhile, my suggestion is you open **two shells**. In one you run `node server.js` and in the other you run `npm run dev` as usual.

Comment: Ah, great, I didn't see the comment. Glad it worked!